# Using arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management on Shapefile and Feature Class

Tags: arcpy, geoprocessing, error-000840

The larger goal with this code is to create a temporary polygon based on the calculated coordinates (which it does), then to see if the polygon intersects with the "unobscured_FC". After I run the select by location the polygon will be deleted, and all sorts of other hilarity will ensue. I only need the temporary polygon for the select.

Now, I've read that you can't run arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management() on shapefiles or feature classes, which is why I tried to make feature layers from the two. However, despite that, I'm getting this error:

> ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
>   The value cannot be a feature class
>   ERROR 000840: The value is not a Raster Layer.
>   ERROR 000840: The value is not a Mosaic Layer.
>   Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute).

I've searched thoroughly for an answer to this problem, and they all appear to be telling me that I need to do exactly what I'm already doing.

How am I failing here to make both of these into feature layers?

Code below...

```
unobscured_FC = r"C:\example.gdb\example_FC"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(unobscured_FC, "unobscured_lyr")

#These coordinates are calculated above in a code block I've excluded...
coordList = [[[Xmax,Ymax], [Xmin,Ymax], [Xmin,Ymin], [Xmax,Ymin]]]
point = arcpy.Point()
array = arcpy.Array()
featureList = []

for feature in coordList:
    for coordPair in feature:
        point.X = coordPair[0]
        point.Y = coordPair[1]
        array.add(point)     
    array.add(array.getObject(0))    
    polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array)    
    array.removeAll()
    featureList.append(polygon)

tempShape = os.path.join(sys.path[0], "temp.shp")
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(featureList, tempShape)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(tempShape, "tempShape_lyr")

arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("unobscured_lyr", "INTERSECT",   "tempShape_lyr", "", "NEW_SELECTION")
```

Comment: The first line starts with " and ends with ', one or the other. Both are valid string delimiters in python but you must match them, if you start with " you need to end with ".

Comment: @ Michael Miles-Stimson I fixed it. It's not like that in the actual code. I had to change the file path when posting.

Comment: I don't know if `MakeFeatureLayer_management` will work on shapefiles. Can you copy your temp polygon into a temp GDB instead?

Comment: @Mintx I will try that and get back to you. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Make feature layer works with any feature class, shapefiles included. What line gives you the error? I"m thinking it's the Copy Features... you're trying to insert a geometry into the temp shape which isn't quite right. It looks like you're making a polygon (or polygons) from a list of points and then you want to use that to select from unobscured_FC is that right?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Yes - that's what I'm trying to do, but the error I'm getting is telling me "The value cannot be a feature class", and that it's occurring here: "Failed to execute (SelectLayerByAttribute)", isn't it? Seems like all the other stuff is working, but that the select function thinks it's getting a feature class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up working and returning a count of 1 - which it should have:

```
unobscured_FC = r"C:\example.gdb\example_FC"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(unobscured_FC, "unobscured_lyr")


SR = arcpy.Describe(unobscured_FC).spatialReference
tempShape = os.path.join(sys.path[0], "temp.shp")
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(sys.path[0], "temp.shp","POLYGON",spatial_reference=SR)
array = arcpy.Array()
point = arcpy.Point()
featureList = []

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
for feature in coordList:
    for coordPair in feature:
        point.X = coordPair[0]
        point.Y = coordPair[1]
        array.add(point)     
    array.add(array.getObject(0))    
    polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array)    
    array.removeAll()
    featureList.append(polygon)

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(featureList, tempShape)
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(tempShape, "tempShape_lyr")

arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("unobscured_lyr", "INTERSECT",   "tempShape_lyr", "", "NEW_SELECTION")

polyCursor = arcpy.SearchCursor("unobscured_lyr")
polyRow = polyCursor.next()
count = 0


while polyRow:
    count = count + 1
    polyRow = polyCursor.next()

print count
```

After adding the spatial reference it still wasn't working. But once I added the overwrite feature it did. Not sure why that is. I'd love an explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that [CopyFeatures](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//001700000035000000) doesn't want to take a list of polygons and make it into a feature class, it *might* work that way but as the spatial reference isn't set the polygon objects are incomplete. The help docs say the input must be either `Feature Layer;Raster Catalog Layer`.

Reading the [writing new Geometries](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Writing_geometries/002z0000001v000000/) in the Esri help docs will give you a better understanding, but I think you've seen that page before as you're creating the geometries just fine.

This is how I would normally create a geometry from known points:

```
SR = arcpy.SpatialReference(28356) # this example is MGA94 Zone 56 (Brisbane, Sydney, Newcastle) change to match your data
tempShape = os.path.join(sys.path[0], "temp.shp")

# Create a new empty feature class
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(sys.path[0], "temp.shp","POLYGON",spatial_reference=SR)

coordList = [[[Xmax,Ymax], [Xmin,Ymax], [Xmin,Ymin], [Xmax,Ymin]]]
point = arcpy.Point()
array = arcpy.Array()

with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(tempShape,"SHAPE@") as ICur:
    for feature in coordList:
            for coordPair in feature:
                    point.X = coordPair[0]
                    point.Y = coordPair[1]
                    array.add(point)     
            array.add(array.getObject(0)) # that's right, add the first to the last

            # make a polygon from the array
            polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array)
            polygon.spatial_reference = SR # set spatial reference

            ICur.insertRow(polygon) # insert it into the feature class

            array.removeAll() # get ready for the next one
```

Then continue your code as normal to select layer by location.

Comment: Right on. It might take me a day or two to test this out but I'll get back to when I do. And, thanks for the info. I've been through a number of the ESRI help pages but after a while my eyes start to glaze over...

Comment: Been there, done that, got the bags under my eyes to prove it. Hope it works for you - it's only part code, not a full program, so I can't test it by executing it.. I'll leave that up to you. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I'm working on this now, still haven't given up, and am getting the error "argument must be sequence of values". trying to figure out what that's all about.

Comment: On what line? Seeing as this is a different error I recommend to post the updated code, the full error message and any new details in a new question and reference this post for history.

Comment: Apologies... I've fiddle with it so much now I don't have the exact same code. It was in the ICur.insertRow(polygon) line.

Comment: So... I added "arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True" before the for loop in my original code, and it worked... I also added a spatial ref to my tempShape, but it didn't work until after I added the overwrite feature.